# Multi Delete Lightning DataTable Using Checkbox?

Tags: apex, lightning

I was Experimenting with lightning:datatable, trying to delete multiple records using checkbox.
Component:-

```
<aura:component controller="DatatableController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

    <!--Declare Attributes-->
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsCount" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsDetails" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsList" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="maxRowSelection" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="enableInfiniteLoading" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="initialRows" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowsToLoad" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalNumberOfRows" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="loadMoreStatus" type="String" default="Please scroll down to load more data"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowNumberOffset" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowsToAdd" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="currentCount" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="defaultSortDirection" type="String"/>

    <!--Declare Handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <!--Component Start-->
    <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large" style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                             data="{!v.data}"
                             keyField="Id"
                             showRowNumberColumn="true"
                             rowNumberOffset="0"
                             onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                             selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"
                             maxRowSelection="{!v.maxRowSelection}"
                             onrowselection="{!c.handleSelectedRow}"
                             enableInfiniteLoading="true"
                             loadMoreOffset="{!v.loadMoreOffset}"
                             sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                             sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                             defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection }"
                             onsort="{!c.handleColumnSorting}"
                             onloadmore="{!c.handleLoadMoreContacts}"/>
        <br/>
        <div class="slds-float_left">
            <strong>Total Rows : {!v.totalNumberOfRows}</strong>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <strong>Selected Rows: {!v.selectedRowsCount }</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-float_right">
            <strong>{!v.loadMoreStatus}</strong>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="slds-float_left">
            <lightning:button label="Delete Selected Contacts"  variant="brand" onclick="{!c.deleteSelectedRows}"/>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Component End-->
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js:-

```
   ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getTotalNumberOfContacts(component);
        helper.getColumnAndAction(component);
        helper.getContacts(component);
    },

    handleLoadMoreContacts: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", true);
        component.set('v.loadMoreStatus', 'Loading....');
        helper.getMoreContacts(component, component.get('v.rowsToLoad')).then($A.getCallback(function (data) {
            if (component.get('v.data').length == component.get('v.totalNumberOfRows')) {
                component.set('v.enableInfiniteLoading', false);
                component.set('v.loadMoreStatus', 'No more data to load');
            } else {
                var currentData = component.get('v.data');
                var newData = currentData.concat(data);
                component.set('v.data', newData);
                component.set('v.loadMoreStatus', 'Please scroll down to load more data');
            }
            event.getSource().set("v.isLoading", false);
        }));
    },

    handleSelectedRows: function (component, event, helper) {
        var data = component.get('v.data');
        var selectedRowList =  component.get("v.selectedRowsList");
        console.log('selectedRowList-' + selectedRowList);
    },

    handleSelectedRow: function(component, event, helper){
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        component.set("v.selectedRowsCount", selectedRows.length);
        let obj =[] ; 
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            obj.push({Name:selectedRows[i].Name});
        }
        component.set("v.selectedRowsDetails", JSON.stringify(obj) );
        component.set("v.selectedRowsList", event.getParam('selectedRows'));
    },

    handleRowAction: function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        switch (action.name) {
            case 'new':
                helper.createContactRecord(component, event);
                break;
            case 'edit':
                helper.editContactRecord(component, event);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                helper.deleteContactRecord(component, event);
                break;
            case 'view':
                helper.viewContactRecord(component, event);
                break;
        }
    },

    handleColumnSorting: function (component, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        component.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        component.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(component, fieldName, sortDirection);
    },

    deleteSelectedRows: function (component, event, helper) {
        var selectedRows = component.get('v.selectedRows');
        var selectedIds = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
        }
         helper.deleteSelectedHelper(component, event, selectedIds);
    },
})
```

Helper:-

```
deleteSelectedHelper: function(component, event, selectedIds) {

    var action = component.get( 'c.deleteRecords' );
    action.setParams({
        "lstRecordId": selectedIds,
    });
    console.log("****Id****",selectedIds);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {           
        // Getting the state from response
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
            // Getting the response from server
            var dataMap = response.getReturnValue();
            // Checking if the status is success
            if(dataMap.status=='success') {
                // Setting the success toast which is dismissable ( vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Success!',
                    'type': 'success',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                // Fire success toast event ( Show toast )
                toastEvent.fire();            
                window.location.reload();
            }
            // Checking if the status is error 
            else if(dataMap.status=='error') {
                // Setting the error toast which is dismissable ( vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Error!',
                    'type': 'error',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                // Fire error toast event ( Show toast )
                toastEvent.fire();                
            }
        } else {
            // Show an alert if the state is incomplete or error
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
        //this.onLoad(component, event);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Server Side Controller:-

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List < String > deleteRecords(List < String > lstRecordId) {
        // for store Error Messages  
        List < String > oErrorMsg = new List < String > ();
        // Query Records for delete where id in lstRecordId [which is pass from client side controller] 
        List < Contact > lstDeleteRec = [select Id from contact where id IN: lstRecordId];
        Database.DeleteResult[] DR_Dels = Database.delete(lstDeleteRec, false);
        // Iterate through each returned result
        for (Database.DeleteResult dr: DR_Dels) {
            if (dr.isSuccess()) {
                system.debug('successfully deleted');
                // Operation was successful
            } else {
                // Operation failed, so get all errors   
                oErrorMsg.add('');
                for (Database.Error err: dr.getErrors()) {
                    // add Error message to oErrorMsg list and return the list
                    oErrorMsg.add(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return oErrorMsg;

    }
```

My Question is how to get the Record Id's of Selected Rows and store those in a list in controller.js? Currently That array is returning null.
Could Someone Fill in the Logic and Explain?
Thanks!!

[image: This is the Debug from Lightning Inspector]

Answer (score 2):

Your `v.selectedRows` attribute should be automatically populated with the subset of the `v.data` row objects that are selected. So loop over the `v.selectedRows` collection and pick out the `Id` attribute of each adding it to an array.

Example:

```
var selectedRows = component.get('v.selectedRows');
var selectedIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
    selectedIds.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
}
```

and then:

```
    action.setParams({
        "lstRecordId": selectedIds
    });
```

Comment: I am Getting  Failed to save Component.js: ESLINT_ERROR: {c:COMPONENT - CONTROLLER} line:col [215:14] --> Parsing error: Unexpected token = : Source I mean Error At for Loop Var=0

Comment: Ah! I guess you missed i at var i = 0

Comment: Still Not Getting ID's , Added Full Controller and Helper Code.Appreciate the help

Comment: Currently That  selectedIds = []; is showing null

Comment: Woops on the missing variable. Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedRows[i]))` to see the fields of the row; I was guessing `Id`.

Comment: @keith C i have read one method getselectedrecord() related to the same functionality in lightning:datatable.

Comment: @KeithC Could you please Check the Image I added.

Comment: @sanketkumar Could you give me a link or example for that please

Comment: @sanketkumar Yeah I think that is a good way to go. I noticed he already had a `selectedRows` setting; I think either should work.

Comment: https://rajvakati.com/2018/02/18/usage-of-lightningdatatable/   here it is demonstrated